# How to communicate with a remote node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a geth instance running on a server and I'd like to be able to interact with it from other machines. I tried a lot of things but they cant connect.

How do you proceed to, lets say being able to act on that node from an external source?

Tried:
In console:

`geth attach http://remote_ip:8545`

`geth attach --rpcaddr remote_ip --rpcport 8545`

In a webpage with web3:

`web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://remote_ip:8545"));`

Comment: Please add what you tried, so we can help you better. There are more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, let's see one by one

```
geth attach http://remote_ip:8545
```

Won't work: as `geth attach` accepts as a parameter an `ipc` entry (this is just a unix socket). There is a way to expose sockets remotely using `socat`. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to find it.

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://remote_ip:8545"));
```

This one, connects with the remote `RPC` (not the same as the `IPC`). You need to expose your `RPC` while launching `geth`, with the options

```
--rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

**SECURITY WARNING**: Exposing both IPC or RPC conveys a security risk, as anybody able to find your machine, will have access. There is no built-in authentication inside `geth`.

**WHAT COULD YOU DO INSTEAD**

I encourage you to adopt a more secure approach: Use SSH and attach this way

```
ssh -i <your private SSL key filepath> user@remote_ip "geth attach ipc:///<path to datadir>/geth.ipc"
```

Will open you an ssh tunnel to operate with the console. This is as secure and encrypted as it can be.

Comment: Do you think I could do the SSh approach for mobiles phones users?

Comment: If you find the right libraries to do the connections, why not? Be advised, anyways  that you will need to distribute the private key or a user, password of your site. If you want to use a professional maintained synchronized RPC node of mainnet or ropsten, you could use INFURA instead (disclaimer, I am the founder) -> infura.io